# multiple Intel OpenMP libraries in one application can cause correctness problems

Tags: dll, openmp, intel

Intel page says:

> Because multiple OpenMP libraries in one appliation causes performance problems (too many threads) and may cause correctness problems if more than one copy is initialized.

We link our library with libiomp5md.dll and distribute it with it. Our customer has a problem that he uses another 3rd party library which uses libiomp5mt.lib. And it won't be an easy process to get rebuild of that 3rd party application with latest Intel MKL.

I'm not able to find what does exactly "correctness problems if more than one copy is initialized" mean. Could you possibly explain or give some examples of what "copy" is and what "more than one copy" is?

Answer (score 0):

A "copy" means an instance of the OpenMP library in memory at run-time.  As long as all the code was *dynamically* linked against libiopm5md.dll, there should not be a problem -- you should end up with a single instance of the OpenMP run-time.  If, however, DLL "A" is statically linked with the OpenMP library and another DLL "B" is dynamically linked, you could end up with two copies of the library, one inside "A" and another dynamically loaded for sake of "B".

An example of a correctness concern is that threadprivate variables were once implemented using a hashtable inside the library, and so two copies would each have their own hashtable.  So given a threadprivate variable "X", a thread might see it have different locations inside DLLs "A" and "B" in the same thread.

Another example of correctness problem is moving pointers between DLLs.  One DLL can allocate memory and send the pointer to another.  If another DLL tries to deallocate the pointer the result will depend on whether the DLLs use the same instance of memory allocator or not.

And more subtle problems may arise from names conflict.  If two copies of the OpenMP runtime work in the application, some code may unexpectedly call wrong instance of the OpenMP.  The result may be silent wrong execution.

Actually, carefully written code may work well having multiple instances of the OpenMP runtime in memory, but we cannot guarantee this for any code.

Andrey